# Category Section Using Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, html, css, bootstrap-modal, font-awesome

I'm finding it very difficult achieving an L shaped category section with featured ads placed beside the featured ad. I'm using bootstrap because of the responsive nature, its the only option I know.

Please heres [SAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev528.jpg) of what I'm trying to achieve.

Also these are my lines of codes:

```html
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-5x" style="background-color: #6fbf4e;"></i><br> <center>CARS</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-television fa-5x" style="background-color: #556266;"></i><br> <center>ELECTRONICS</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones fa-5x" style="background-color: #eb686e;"></i><br> <center>ENTERTAINMENT</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-5x" style="background-color: #4a8c9c;"></i><br><center>JOBS</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-5x" style="background-color: #1693eb;"></i><br> <center>REAL ESTATE</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-5x" style="background-color: #fc011f;"></i><br> <center>RESTAURANTS</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-5x" style="background-color: #6fbf4e;"></i><br> <center>EDUCATION</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-5x" style="background-color: #556266;"></i><br> <center>SERVICES</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-5x" style="background-color: #eb686e;"></i><br> <center>EVENTS</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female fa-5x" style="background-color: #4a8c9c;"></i><br><center>FASHION</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paw fa-5x" style="background-color: #1693eb;"></i><br> <center>ANIMALS & PETS</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-5x" style="background-color: #fc011f;"></i><br> <center>MORE</a></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
    
    <div><a href="#"><img class="featured" src="images/Featured-Ad.jpg" ></a></div>
```

Please I need help guys, I've been trying to achieve this for too long now but I'm getting nowhere. Thanks

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding rows in between your categories just have one row and then add your columns inside that row.  So add your featured section first then your categories should fall into place.  Like so:

Here is a fiddle with some random css and the following markup [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/h7kf43au/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6 featured-section">
      <a class="featured" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 category"><a href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, but when I resize the screen some part of the image cuts off, my images are 145px x 145px. I had to use png images because font awesome icons wasn't displaying on firefox.

Comment: If you are going to use images you may have issues with reponsiveness because of image resolution.  You could remove the overflow:hidden from the category a like I have in the fiddle or you will have to give each image a width and height and match the height to the div then center the image in the div so when it resizes the image will remain the same size like so https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/m5m38jn3/.  If I were you I would go with font awesome icons though they should work in firefox just fine hot sure why you are having issues.  Updated the fiddle in my answer with font awesome and it works

Comment: Wow..thanks a million, you've no idea how long I've been on this. One last question pleeease, how can I add individual background colour to each category.  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 categ"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-television"style="background-color: #556266;"></i>Electronics</span></a></div>  This didn't work for me, it only gave  the font icon a background. Thanks again

Comment: Add it to the <a> tag <a href="#" style="background:#55626;"><i></i></a>

Comment: Awesome! Many thanx Mate!